# How to set plural label values in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have chart.js (chartjs) all set up on my site and working wonderfully!

For my labels I declared:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%> <%}%>(<%= value %> votes)",
```

But I would like that when there is just one vote it sets a label of 'vote' instead of 'votes', is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use another if statement, for example:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if(label){%><%=label%> <%}%>(<%=value%> 
                  <%if(value != 1){%>votes<%}else{%>vote<%}%>)"
```